# Append two multi dimensional array and then sort by timestamp value in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two multi dimensional arrays that I wanna first combine (append) and then sort all by a timestamp value.

Below are the two arrays that are already sorted by their cell value `[timestamp]`.

What I want to do is:

- Combine `$array1` and `$array2` (e.g. as one array - say `$array3`)
- Sort that one large array by `[timestamp]`

### Here are both arrays:

```
$array1 = 

Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 100989
            [fullname] => John Dobbs
            [email] => john_dobbs@email.com
            [timestamp] => 1533116498
            [uid] => 1349
        )
    [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 32989
                [fullname] => Terry White
                [email] => some@email.com
                [timestamp] => 1533116498
                [uid] => 223
            )
    [2] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 94883
                [fullname] => Dan Rogers
                [email] => some@email.com
                [timestamp] => 1533116412
                [uid] => 923
            )
    [3] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 78382
                [fullname] => Dan Rogers
                [email] => some@email.com
                [timestamp] => 1533111083
                [uid] => 23
            )


$array2 = 
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 100989
            [fullname] => John Dobbs
            [email] => john_dobbs@email.com
            [timestamp] => 1533111068
            [aid] => 802531
            [uid] => 1259
        )
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 100989
            [fullname] => John Dobbs
            [email] => john_dobbs@email.com
            [timestamp] => 1533111063
            [aid] => 802531
            [uid] => 1259
        )
    [2] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 155854
                [fullname] => Terry White
                [email] => some@email.com
                [timestamp] => 1533088445
                [aid] => 802069
                [uid] => 1833
            )
    [3] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 165212
                [fullname] => Dan Rogers
                [email] => some@email.com
                [timestamp] => 1533080179
                [aid] => 801761
                [uid] => 1831
            )
    [4] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 116940
                [fullname] => Dan Rogers
                [email] => some@email.com
                [timestamp] => 1533059095
                [aid] => 801343
                [uid] => 1239
            )
```

Comment: And what's the problem? Merging arrays with `array_merge`, sorting with `usort`.

Comment: For sorting i would recommend the [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) function.

Comment: how can I make sure that usort sorts the array by [timestamp]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think following snippet should work for you,

```
$array = array_merge($array1, $array2);

function cmp($a, $b)
{
    return strcmp($a->timestamp, $b->timestamp);
}

usort($array, "cmp");
```

Comment: Thanks. can we sort it descending? higher first? currently it is sorting lower first.

Comment: Did this to sort in descending `return strcmp($b->timestamp, $a->timestamp);`. Would that be ok?

Comment: Yes i think you should try once if not work than let me know